# The right way to remove an item from a linked list

Tags: pointers

In this [Slashdot interview](http://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions) Linus Torvalds is quoted as saying:

> I've seen too many people who delete a singly-linked list entry by keeping track of the "prev" entry, and then to delete the entry, doing something like
>
> if (prev)
>   prev->next = entry->next;
> else
>   list_head = entry->next;
>
> and whenever I see code like that, I just go "This person doesn't understand pointers". And it's sadly quite common.
>
> People who understand pointers just use a "pointer to the entry pointer", and initialize that with the address of the list_head. And then as they traverse the list, they can remove the entry without using any conditionals, by just doing a "*pp = entry->next".

As a PHP developer I have not touched pointers since *Introduction to C* in university a decade ago. However, I feel that this is a type of situation that I should at least be familiar with. **What is Linus talking about?** To be honest, if I were asked to implement a linked list and to remove an item, the above 'wrong' way is the way that I would go about it. **What do I need to know to code as Linus says best?**

I am asking here rather than on Stack Overflow as I'm not actually having an issue with this in production code.

Comment: What he's saying is that when you need to store the location of the `prev`, instead of storing the entire node, you can just store the location of `prev.next`, since that' the only thing you're interested in. A pointer to a pointer. And if you do that, you avoid the silly `if`, since now you don't have the awkward case of `list_head` being a pointer from outside a node. The pointer to the head of the list is then semantically the same as the pointer to the next node.

Comment: @Ordous: I see, thanks. Why a comment? That is a concise, clear, and illuminating answer.

Comment: @Ordous Everything involved in that code snippet is a pointer, so his point can't have anything to do with storing the entire node vs storing a pointer to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using my L331 MS Paint skills:

[image]

The original solution is to point to Nodes via `curr`. In that case you check if the next node after `curr` has the delete value, and if so reset the `curr` node `next` pointer. The problem is that there is no node that points to the head of the list. That means there has to be a special case to check it.

What Linus (likely) proposes instead is not to save the pointer to the current examined node, but rather the pointer to the pointer to the current node (labelled `pp`). The operation is the same - if the `pp` pointer points to a node with the right value, you reset the `pp` pointer.

The difference comes in the very beginning of the list. While there is no Node that points to the head of the list, there is, in fact, a pointer to the head of the list. And it is just the same a pointer to a node, just as another nodes `next` pointer. Hence there is no need for a special clause for the beginning of the list.

Comment: Ah I see now....you learn something new every day.

Comment: I think you describe things correctly, but I would suggest that the proper solution is to have `list_head` point to something with a `next` node that points to the first real data item (and have `prev` initialized to that same dummy object).  I don't like the idea of having `prev` point to something of different type, since such tricks may introduce Undefined Behavior via aliasing, and make code needlessly sensitive to structure layout.

Comment: @supercat That's exactly the point. Instead of having `prev` pointing to Nodes, it points to pointers. It always points to something of the same type, namely a pointer to a Node. Your suggestion is essentially the same - have `prev` point to something "with a `next` node". If you discard the shell you just get the initial `list_head` pointer. Or in other words - something that is defined only by having a pointer to the next node, is semantically equivalent to a pointer to a node.

Comment: @Ordous: That makes sense, though it presupposes that `list_head` and `next` will hold the same "kind" of pointer.  Not an issue in C, perhaps, but perhaps problematic in C++.

Comment: @supercat I always assumed that's the "canonical" representation of a linked list, language-agnostic. But I'm not proficient enough to judge whether it makes a difference between C and C++ really, and what are the standard implementations there.

Answer (score 14):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Code Example

```c
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start by pointing to the head pointer.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//    (next_ptr)
//         |
//         v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]----->[to_remove]----->[....]
Node** next_ptr = &list->head;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Search the list for the matching entry.
// After searching:
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                  (next_ptr)
//                                       |
//                                       v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]----->[to_remove]----->[next]
while (*next_ptr != to_remove) // or (*next_ptr)->val != to_remove->val
{
    Node* next_node = *next_ptr
    next_ptr = &next_node->next;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dereference the next pointer and set it to the next node's next
// pointer.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//                                           (next_ptr)
//                                                |
//                                                v
// [head]----->[..]----->[..]----->[..]---------------------->[next]
*next_ptr = to_remove->next;
```

If we need some logic to destroy the node, then we can just add a line of code at the end:

```
// Deallocate the node which is now stranded from the list.
free(to_remove);
```